# Python Matplotlib Specific Figure Generation Works on One PC but Not Other

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
x = Firstyr_df['FIRST_YEAR_TOTAL'][Firstyr_df['FIRST_YEAR_TOTAL'] > 0]
y = Secondyr_df['SECOND_YEAR_TOTAL'][Secondyr_df['SECOND_YEAR_TOTAL'] > 0]
z = Thirdyr_df['THIRD_YEAR_TOTAL'][Thirdyr_df['THIRD_YEAR_TOTAL'] > 0]

bins = np.linspace(0, 10000, 1000)
plt.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.5, label='Year 1')
plt.hist(y, bins, alpha=0.5, label='Year 2')
plt.hist(z, bins, alpha=0.5, label='Year 3')
plt.xlim(0,300)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

It is for an overlapping histogram.  It runs fine on one machine but not the other.  I have run a 'conda update conda' so everything should be identical.  Can anyone provide insight?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same matplotlib version in both computers?

Comment: What messages this code produced on the other machine? Any warnings or errors?

Comment: @Luis I ran 'conda update conda' on both - how can I check specific matplotlib version?  Dumb question I know.

Comment: @StanleyR `KeyError: 0L`.  If I only plot `x` is works - but only for the series `x`.  If I try `y` or `z` alone I still get this error.  There are no `NaN`s in any of the series

Comment: @Windstorm1981: You can check versions like: `import matplotlib`
`print( matplotlib.__version__  )`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It was a version problem.  The machine not rendering the histograms was an older version.  Sorry to waste your time.